# Function cannot open file after py2exe compile

Tags: python, py2exe, rdkit

I'm using [rdkit](http://www.rdkit.org/docs/).

After a build using `py2exe`, when I call the `Draw.MolToImage` method there is an error:

```
Warning: unable to load font metrics from dir 
C:\pythonApp\dist\library.zip\rd
kit\sping\PIL\pilfonts
Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "app.py", line 470, in <module>
    img=Draw.MolToImage(part[i])
    File "rdkit\Chem\Draw\__init__.pyc", line 124, in MolToImage
    File "rdkit\Chem\Draw\MolDrawing.pyc", line 536, in AddMol
    File "rdkit\Chem\Draw\MolDrawing.pyc", line 351, in _drawLabel
    File "rdkit\Chem\Draw\spingCanvas.pyc", line 74, in addCanvasText
    File "rdkit\sping\PIL\pidPIL.pyc", line 333, in drawString
ValueError: bad font: Font(12,0,0,0,'helvetica')`
```

There is no difference if I put these files into `library.zip` (to `\rdkit\sping\PIL\pilfonts`) or just into the `dist` folder and change paths in [`pidPIL.py`](http://rdkit.sourcearchive.com/documentation/201106plus-pdfsg-1build1/pidPIL_8py_source.html) to valid; the application still cannot open `metrics.dat`.

Without the `py2exe` conversion, everything works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using 'data_files' in your setup.py to include the pilfonts folder?

E.g. something along these lines:

```
setup(

    data_files = [("pilfonts", glob.glob("\rdkit\sping\PIL\pilfonts\*.*"),

    options = {"py2exe": {"compressed": 2,
    # etc etc
)
```

Comment: I've tried your way and also [this solution](http://crazedmonkey.com/blog/python/pkg_resources-with-py2exe.html) but without any results.

Comment: What/where does pidPil.py expect the folder to be?  Add a print/breakpoint to the figure this out.

Comment: Paths were correct, but app couldn't open the file. I "fixed" it in other way. Just changed rendering lib to `py2cairo`. No `PIL` files - no problem.